# jQuery change all instance of text to html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

For example, I have a text that goes like `{Lorem}` all over the DOM. How do I go about changing all instances of it to

`<p>Lorem ipsum dolor imet</p>`?

I'm trying this:

```
var loremReplace = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor imet</p>';
var content = $('body').html().replace(/\{Lorem\}/g, loremReplace);
$('body').html(content);
```

But obviously, I'm doing something wrong because it's not working. Also, how do I go about it if `{Lorem}` exists outside of `<body>`, like it's in `<head>` part instead?

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XrVSv/

Comment: This is exactly what regular expressions were made for, there's no better use than simply parsing HTML and doing string replacements on the entire document. You're spot on, great solution.

Comment: Okay now that I see it, it does work as intended. I figured it was conflicting with other scripts in the page though. The other scripts are plugins that manipulate the DOM too. How do I make it work so it doesn't affect the other? Either make it load before the others or load after the others have done their job?

Comment: Okay never mind. `$(window).load()` did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't really need to scape the curly brackets in the replace function:

```
var loremReplace = '<p>Lorem ipsum dolor imet</p>';
var content = $('body').html().replace(/{Lorem}/g, loremReplace);
$('body').html(content);
```

To replace your expression inside the head, you can simply select the `head` tag and proceed as with the `body`:

```
var headReplace = 'Lorem ipsum dolor imet';
var headContent = $('head').html().replace(/{Lorem}/g, headReplace);
$('head').html(headContent);
```

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/meqicuto/2/edit

Comment: Hey, man, thanks for the heads up with the curly brackets and the `head` part. Looks like the problem I was having was it was conflicting with other scripts. Solved it with `$(window).load()`